# Connect an active directory or LDAP with PHP

Tags: php, windows, ldap

I am trying to connect the active directory or LDAP of window with an application ([GLPI](http://glpi-project.org)) made in PHP.

Connection parameters:

Connecting with the server:

```
$ds = ldap_connect($host, $port) // return true

@ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

@ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

@ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_DEREF, $deref_options);
```

Relate connection to server and user and password

```
ldap_bind ($ds, $ login, $ password)
```

returns me:

> "Can not contact LDAP server"

I want to know what can happen with that error message, since in the first method it returns true to me, which means that if it connects to the server.

`RootDN` This is fine and has all the permissions the user I am using.

The default server is fine and I did `ping` and`telnet`.

**Note:** I already downloaded LDAPExplorer and established connection without problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the solution to my problem is to upgrade from GLPI version 9.3.0 to 9.3.3.

Suggestions:

- For users, what could happen to this, verify the messages that GLPI has informs about pending installation packages. So I opted for the update and the connection worked without problem.
- For users who can not update version, verify that apache packages are pending to install or update, also in the installation process in the setup, be very careful installing the entire list that seems pending.

To fix some errors by installing version 9.3.3:

`chown -R apache: apache glpi / files`

`chmod -R 755 glpi / files`

`chown -R apache: apache config`

`chmod -R 755 glpi / config`

also:

`setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1`

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Does the missing : `$ds = ldap_connect ...` like how it is in your code?

It should be something like :

```
$ds = ldap_connect($host, $port);

@ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

@ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

@ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_DEREF, $deref_options);

ldap_bind ($ds, $login, $password)
```

Answer (score 1):

`ldap_connect` does **not** connect to the server as is clearly stated in the [docs](http://php.net/ldap_connect). It merely creates a resource and checks whether the given values are plausible. The actual connection is established with the first command that requires a connection to the server. In this case the `ldap_bind`.

BTW: The "first method" does not return `true` but a resource-handle. Only when you pass something absolutely not parseable it will return `false`. But **never** `true`

I'd recommend using an LDAP-URI instead of the `$host, $port` variation as the PHP-library has to do that otherwise internaly. And it's the only way to f.e. establish an LDAPS-connection.

Comment: I'm running `echo ldap_error($ds);` and it returns true and then I execute `ldap_bind($ds, $login, $password);` and it returns false and then `ldap_error($ds)` returning "Can not contact LDAP server".  I also try putting the ip of the server inside the method, but I get the same result.

Comment: you should use `var_Dump($ds);` instead of the first `echo ldap_error($ds);` to see the actual value of `$ds`. To get more information about the error you might weant to have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-error.php#121881 which describes a way to extract more info about the last error.

Comment: Execute   `var_dump( ldap_error($ds) )` return me  _string(7) "Success"_.

Comment: Execute `var_dump($ds)`  return me _resource(65) of type (ldap link)_